# issue after migrating to windows server 2016

Tags: c#, callback, windows-server-2016, concurrentdictionary

I am working on a server migration from microsoft server 2008 R2 to microsoft server 2016. There is a standalone server in the background which manages the jobs to be run on SAS. We use a ConcurrentDictionary to record the job information. the code works perfectly on the old server, but on the new server, the job information disappears from the ConcurrentDictionary.

the ConcurrentDictionary is updated in callback functions OnProgress and Oncomplete. I have tried to debug the code, but it wont hit breakpoints in these two functions. If I make these functions public and add a reference in the main api, then the callback does not work correctly. Next I plan to try using a xml file to store the job information instead of the ConcurrentDictionary. But I would prefer looking at other options before making big changes in the code.

OnProgress -

```
   private void OnProgress(Messages.JobFeedback feedback)
    {
        operations.AddOrUpdate(feedback.JobId, 
            new SasJobsServiceOperation { Feedback = feedback },
            (id, o) => { o.Feedback = feedback; return o; });
    }
```

OnCompleted -

```
    private void OnCompleted(Messages.JobFeedback feedback, string xmlResult)
    { 
        operations.AddOrUpdate(feedback.JobId, 
            new SasJobsServiceOperation { Feedback = feedback, XmlResult = xmlResult },
            (id, o) => { o.Feedback = feedback; o.XmlResult = xmlResult; return o; });

    }
```

calling function -

```
        this.callback.OnProgress(new Messages.JobFeedback 
        {
            JobId = this.settings.Id,
            PercentComplete = 1,
            FeedbackMessage = "Starting Job on server",
            Status = Messages.StatusCode.Running
        });
```

Comment: I can't imagine that the c# code is working in a different way - I am using bots windows editions, and never encountered differences in this aspect. The problem is most likely related to the architecture of the application, as the communication between two components. If SAS is running as standalone service and your application is communicating with it over some kind of IPC, you should inspect this communication.

Comment: With the problem you have mentioned, it seems that issue is more likely towards the `callback` instead of `ConcurrentDictionary ` If `OnProgress` and `OnCompleted` are not invoked then `ConcurrentDictionary` can't be populated.

Comment: @ZorgoZ - we have verified the communication and it works well.

Comment: @user1672994 -  i think so too, but cant figure out the exact issue

Comment: What kind of IPC is used?

Comment: @ZorgoZ - we use http

Comment: So, SAS is calling back into your app over http? Is your app self-hosted or iis-hosted (or some other appication server)?

Comment: @ZorgoZ - it is IIS hosted

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved. the 'http activation' was disabled in server features. Enabling it got the function call working.